# Subscription not found, creating a new sheet with sorted variables VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am running into an error when I run the below code, The error states that the "Subscription is out of range" and when I debug it jumps to the " Set WSNew = WBMAIN.Worksheets("sheetName") ' Set WSNEW to the new sheetName" line.

The code does creat a new sheet as it is supposed to however the sheer is empty, while it is supposed to carry the WSNew values mentioned in the for loop.

Please see the below code:

```
   Option Explicit
Public WBMAIN As Workbook
Public WSmain As Worksheet
Public WSvl As Worksheet
Public WSNew As Worksheet
Sub Main()

Dim OBdate As String, amount As String, yesno As String, yesno2 As String ' All Variables
Dim OLDr As Long, OLDc As Long, NEWr As Long, NEWc As Long, sheetName As String
Dim VLookupResult As String, complexName As String
Dim FilePath As String

OLDc = 2  ' First Sheet Column
NEWr = 1  ' New Sheet Row
NEWc = 1  ' New Sheet Column

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.path ' File path for this workbook

Set WBMAIN = Workbooks("EVO_MOD") ' set WBMAIN to the entire workbook
Set WSmain = WBMAIN.Worksheets("EVO MOD FORM") ' set WSmain to the first worksheet
Set WSvl = WBMAIN.Worksheets("Vlookup") ' set the Vlookup for the acc no.


complexName = WSmain.Cells(2, 2) ' Complex Name Cell
OBdate = WSmain.Cells(1, 2) ' Date Cell

WBMAIN.Activate ' Activates WBmain
sheetName = "EVO_" + complexName ' Sheet Name
Sheets.Add.Name = sheetName
Set WSNew = WBMAIN.Worksheets(sheetName) ' Set WSNEW to the new sheetName

For OLDr = 13 To 200 ' for 200 lines in the main sheet
    If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc) = 0 Then GoTo exitthis
    If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc) <> 0 Then
        VLookupResult = Application.VLookup(WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc), WSvl.Range("A2:B200"), 2, False)
        'Collect amount and detirmine if debit or credit
        If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) <> " " Then
            amount = WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) ' If Credit is Empty do
            yesno = "Y"
            yesno2 = "N"
        Else
        If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 5) <> " " Then ' if Debit is empty , do
                amount = WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 5)
                yesno = "N"
                yesno2 = "Y"
        Else
        If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 5) = " " & WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) = " " Then GoTo exitthis ' if both cells are blank , skip to exitthis
        End If
            
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 1) = OBdate                   ' Assigning 2 lines of code that prints to WSNew
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 2) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 3) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 4) = amount
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 5) = "N"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 8) = "0"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 10) = VLookupResult
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 11) = yesno
        
        NEWr = NEWr + 1
        
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 1) = OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 2) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 3) = "OB"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 4) = amount
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 5) = "N"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 8) = "0"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 10) = "9990>001"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 11) = yesno2
        End If
        End If
exitthis:
Next OLDr

' Start creating CSV

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Check if Directory exists
' Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim path As String
Dim mycsvfilename As String

mycsvfilename = ThisWorkbook.path & "\EvolutionCSV"


WBMAIN.Sheets("newSheet").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set WSNew = ActiveWorkbook
With WSNew
.SaveAs Filename:=mycsvfilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
' .Close
End With
SetAttr mycsvfilename, vbReadOnly
WBMAIN.Sheets("CSVexport").Delete
WBMAIN.Worksheets("Actions").Activate
err:

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Please advise whether anyone has a solution to this or knows why this problem would occur

Comment: You need `Set WSNew = WBMAIN.Worksheets(sheetName)` as otherwise it is looking for a sheet called "sheetName" as it is in quotes. Anything in quotes is treated literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `sheetName` as a string by enclosing it with quotes so either you change it to :

```
Set WSNew = WBMAIN.Worksheets(sheetName)
```

**OR**

you can set `WSNew` to the new sheet when you are adding then change its name, like this:

```
Set WSNew = WBMAIN.Sheets.Add
WSNew.Name = sheetName
```

EDIT:

Code block for the `For` loop portion:

```
For OLDr = 13 To 200 ' for 200 lines in the main sheet
    If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc) = 0 Then GoTo exitthis
    If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc) <> 0 Then
        
        VLookupResult = Application.VLookup(WSmain.Cells(OLDr, OLDc), WSvl.Range("A2:B200"), 2, False)
        'Collect amount and detirmine if debit or credit
        If WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) <> " " Then
            amount = WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) ' If Credit is Empty do
            yesno = "Y"
            yesno2 = "N"
        ElseIf WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 5) <> " " Then ' if Debit is empty , do
            amount = WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 5)
            yesno = "N"
            yesno2 = "Y"
        Else
            GoTo exitthis ' if both cells are blank , skip to exitthis
        End If
            
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 1) = OBdate                   ' Assigning 2 lines of code that prints to WSNew
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 2) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 3) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 4) = amount
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 5) = "N"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 8) = "0"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 10) = VLookupResult
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 11) = yesno
        
        NEWr = NEWr + 1
        
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 1) = OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 2) = "OB " + OBdate
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 3) = "OB"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 4) = amount
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 5) = "N"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 8) = "0"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 10) = "9990>001"
        WSNew.Cells(NEWr, 11) = yesno2
    End If
exitthis:
Next OLDr
```

Comment: Thats perfect ! thank you

It is now giving me a " Next without for " error , however there for is declared at the start of the code. Please advise whether you would also have a fix for this ?

Comment: @KyleStranger I just copy/pasted your code in a module and it compile fine. Maybe you can update your question with the amended version. Btw, you can remove this line `OLDr = 13` as it is now used as a loop so there's no need to assign a value to it.

Comment: Hi Raymon , I have amended the code to what I currently have on my side and removed OLDr as requested

Comment: @KyleStranger I'm not saying it is the issue but it might be a bug so maybe close and open the workbook. Can you explain what is the logic for assigning `amount`, `yesno` and `yesno2` variables? your `If..Else..End If` statements look weird and might not be doing what you think it is.

Comment: the amount variable is used to fetch the credit/debit balance from col 4&5 , once it determines whether the value is in 4 or 5 it changes the value if yesno to "yes" if its row 4 and "no" if its row 5 , the yesno2 variable has to be the opposite of the first yesno... I also feel like the problem is with the if statement , however i can't seem to figure out what is causing the errors. I have also restarted my program as requested

Comment: @KyleStranger `WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) <> " "` Have you ever tried to test if this will ever become false? Usually we will test if the cell is empty by `WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) <> ""` or `WSmain.Cells(OLDr, 4) <> vbNullString`. Currently it only return false if the cell does have 1 space. (Unless, your worksheet does have 1 space all over then it's fine)

Comment: @KyleStranger I have updated my answer with the `For` loop. Try it out and if it doesn't work, please post a new question (as this particular question has been resolved).

Comment: thank you so much for your assistance. The code is running as well as it can for this question. I will post a new question regarding the VlookupResult function as it would need some changes.

Comment: @KyleStranger If this answer is sufficient for your question, please accept it by clicking the tick beside it.